# WSO2 IS 5.1 adding @carbon.super to username while authenticating with Password Grant

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

We recently migrated (registry and user store) from WSO2 IS 5.0 to WSO2 IS 5.1 as per instructions at [WSO2 migration guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Upgrading+from+a+Previous+Release#UpgradingfromaPreviousRelease-Upgradingthedatabase). After migrating and successfully bringing up the WSO2 IS server, when we are trying to authenticate existing user with /oauth2/token endpoint the authentication is failing. We can see user along with user attributes in user store.
On WSO2 server we are seeing error -

```
{org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.PasswordGrantHandler} -  Token request with Password Grant Type received. Username : <username>@carbon.superScope : openid, Authentication State : false
```

This is migrated user so we can not change the user name. I tried googling to disable the multi tenancy with 5.1 as we do not use that feature, but no luck.

This is blocking us from moving to newer version of WSO2.

Has Any one fixed this?

Modified the SP to disable domain name as per instructions from Gusto2 -
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3m5BX.png)

But still same results.

Comment: If you open the configuration page for the service provider (application), there should be a checkbox somewhere (I don't recall exact place) to include the tenant domain with login. As far I remember (after a long time) after the migration this is by default on, so you may disable that.

Comment: Thanks Gusto2. I tried to un-check all the check boxes for my SP but no change. Interestingly when I try with admin user to access the token it works even though the user name is just admin. Also I created one new user and tried to get the token, it worked. Problem is with users added through API.

Comment: couldn't be a problem with the passwords? what userstore do you use? ldap? db? can the user authenticate if you change its password?

Comment: Its DB user store. I am able to change the password of the user through WSO2 console and I can see new password in UM_USER table. But when I try to access token with new password it fails with message user name or password do not match.

Comment: @Vinay Have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

on the duo identity provider configuration page, under federated authenticators, put "true" in the "disable tenant domain" box

Answer (score 0):

This solution may help. You can go to your identity server and navigate to the service. Now click on edit button of your target service and go to **Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration** section and uncheck following options-

1. Use tenant domain in local subject identifier
2. Use user store domain in local subject identifier

**I am showing in the image. Follow the red mark box -**

[image: wso2 config image]